# Breakpoints not resolving on Xcode 14 (Turn to outlines when app is run)

Tags: breakpoints, xcode14

We are running into an issue where breakpoints are not resolving on Xcode 14 (The same break points on Xcode 13.4.1 are working fine). They change to an outline when we run our app

[image]

This is code that is definitely executing. What's really strange is the break points will work occasionally, and work for a few runs before they stop working again.

I have tried all the usual fixes

1. Cleaned the build
2. Cleaned Derived data
3. Restarted Xcode
4. Restarted the machine
5. Re-cloned the repo to see if starting fresh helps

I have also tried/verified

- Removing all symbol stripping
- Ensuring the DSYM is getting generated and is loaded in the debugger
- Removing all optimization options
- Tried the Xcode 14.1 beta

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In case anyone ends up here with the same problem - For us it turned out to be because we had specified -x and -dead_strip in our "other linker flags". For some reason it worked fine before Xcode 14

Answer (score 0):

I found that I still hold my old Xcode 13.3 in my mac and it showed a ban mark on its icon. After I remove 13.3, everything gone nice. May this help you :)

Comment: But I also reverted my project path too, didnt know which helped. :(

Answer (score 0):

Reset Xcode Preferences: Try resetting your Xcode preferences by deleting the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist file from ~/Library/Preferences/. This will reset all of your Xcode preferences to their default values.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your project has multiple targets. Please make sure that your class is associated with the correct build target.